# How can I check if two elements in a nodeList are identical?

Tags: xml, arrays, nodelist

How can I check if two elements in a NodeList are identical? Ultimately, I'm checking if there are duplicate elements in an XML file.

E.g. I want to throw an exception if something like the following occurs:

```
<type id="foo">
</type>
<type id="foo">
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, compare every element to every other using deep-equal, for example

```
for $i in $nodes
for $j in $nodes
if (deep-equal($i, $j) and not($i is $j))
then error() else ()
```

(This is XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0).

If the number of nodes is very large then this will be inefficient; a better solution would be to group the nodes on some hash function and then only compare nodes in the same group. Devising a good hash function probably requires knowledge of your data. You could then use XSLT 2.0 like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-by="my:hash(.)">
  <xsl:variable name="group" select="current-group()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="
    for $i in $group
    for $j in $group
    if (deep-equal($i, $j) and not($i is $j))
    then error() else ()"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This is only a sketch of a solution of course; you will want to fill in the gaps on error reporting and the like.